# How to deal with LDAP attribute values having $ in them

Tags: ldap, text-formatting, ldif, apacheds

Just beginning with LDAP and have imported outlook records into a directory. that look like this:
[image]

Have also edited individual addresses in in the Apache Directory Studio any number of ways
to show the street, and city, state on separate lines like a conventional address would look
[image]

but later looking at them from the address book they appear as:

[image]

obviously the $ is used to wrap the second part of the address, but is there a way to not show that in the address book output? a different character in substitution?

What is doing this? Apache Diretory Studio is showing it as a comma, but in edit mode it shows nothing.
And does it matter at all? or just a potential confusion for users?

I might add, that adding the contact back to an outlook client pulls in the $

Using ApacheDS which may have some peculiar impact on this or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1778.txt) has the information describing the format of the `postalAddress` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this. I do see that the '$' is part of how the encoding should be, but don't understand what that means, if I want to just show a CrLf instead. Or if it is even possible.

Comment: The `$` is used to separate portions of `t16string` components. Code that desires to display the address should change the record separators to the correct characters according to the local encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the syntax of that attribute?  I happen to know in eDirectory that postalAddress uses a funky syntax that has 6 components.  You would see them # separated in eDirectory.

I wonder if your directory service (undisclosed) has some interesting syntax for this attribute, beyond simple strings?

Comment: I just noted the server which is AcpacheDS, perhaps you are right. I do find it weird that outlook concatenates all these fields anyway, rather than allowing individual fields. Seems ripe for errors in parsing

Comment: Its a bad choice of a field on Outlooks point.